# jquery UI sortable, how can i return the text of moved <li>?

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

what i'm trying to do is to return the text that is contained by the moved li, after the list item was moved. Is there a way to do that? thanks

**EDIT:**

i tried: `$(ui.item).text()` but i get an `ui is not defined error` (i imported just `jquery.js`, `ui.core.js` and `ui.sortable.js` , do i have to import something else?)

**HTML**

```
<ul id="sortable">
    <li><a href="" class="drag">text</a></li>
    <li><a href="" class="drag">another text</a></li>
    <li><a href="" class="drag">more text</a></li>
</ul>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('ul#sortable').sortable({
          handle:'.drag',
          axis:'y',
          update:function(){
               alert($(ui.item).text());
          }
     });
});
```

Comment: Can you show us the rest of your code?

Comment: +1 this helped me figure out how to access the last item moved. thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You haven't named any parameters in your callback function. You need to name them in order to use them:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('ul#sortable').sortable({
          handle:'.drag',
          axis:'y',
          update:function(event, ui){
               alert($(ui.item).text());
          }
     });
});
```